# If then else in Bash for file types

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash on Linux. I try to simple iterate over files in a directory which can be links or executeables. On Links I mention Link and on other files get file version

```
for i in *; do
if test -f "$i"
then
  if test -L "$i"
    then
      echo "File $i,Link"
  else
    echo "File $i,"  readelf -a -W $i |grep SONAME
  fi
fi
done
```

it only workes on the links. 
How would I do it correctly ?
Also some examples mention [ ...] instead of test. What is the difference ?

Thanks for any hint that helps understanding bash !

Comment: `echo "File $i,"` and `readelf -a -W $i |grep SONAME` should be on 2 separate lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `-n` to avoid newline after echo (or `printf` for better portability), and use the `readelf` command on a separate line or it is interpreted as an argument of `echo`.

```
for i in *; do
if test -f "$i"
then
  if test -L "$i"
    then
      echo "File $i,Link"
  else
    printf "File $i,"
    readelf -a -W $i |grep SONAME
  fi
fi
```

Comment: almost there, thanks !It's just that with some link types I get neither Link or File Version

Comment: `echo -n` is not portable.  The proper solution to that is `printf`.

Comment: @tripleee didn't know that subtletly. Edited my post for correctness. Thanks.

Comment: Also, it's good practice to use `printf '%s' "File $i,"`, in case `$i` itself contains a percent sign.